Confusion about finding remainder with polynomial division
P) Find $2019^3+2018^3-1 \mod (2019^2+2018^2)$.

Let $x=2018$, then
$$2019^3+2018^3-1=(x+1)^3+x^3-1=2x^3+3x^2+3x$$
and
$$2019^2+2018^2=(x+1)^2+x^2=2x^2+2x+1$$
we have
$$2x^3+3x^2+3x=\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)(2x^2+2x+1)+x-\frac{1}{2}$$
but if I plug $x=2018$, I have a contradiction because I got rational but remainder should be integer.
Where did I make a mistake? And Can I solve this with polynomial division? Thanks for help.

Hint $\ \color{#c00}2:!(x^2!+!x)\equiv \color{#c00}{-1},\Rightarrow, \color{#c00}{-\frac{1}2}\equiv x^2!+!x,, $ so $,x-\frac{1}2 \equiv x^2!+!2x,[:!\equiv (x!+!1)^2-1:!]\ \ $

Your mistake is at choosing $x+1/2$, a non-integer, as a factor. Choose, say $x+1$ (equivalently, you could use $x$) and you'll get:
$(x+1)(2x^2+2x+1) = 2x^3+4x^2+3x+1 = (2x^3+3x^2+3x)+x^2+1$
Thus, you get $2x^3+3x^2+3x = (x+1)(2x^2+2x+1)-(x^2+1)$
Hence, the remainder is $(2019^2+2018^2)-(2018^2+1) = 2019^2-1$

Since the modulus $2019^2+2018^2$ is odd, $2$ is invertible with inverse
$\dfrac{2019^2+2018^2+1}2=\dfrac{2\cdot2018^2+2\cdot2018+2}2=2018^2+2018+1,$
so the answer is $x-\dfrac12\equiv2018-(2018^2+2018+1)\equiv-2018^2-1\equiv2019^2-1.$
